# Pod written in Swift 4

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift4, codable

I have a question,

can I write a library like Cocoapods pod in Swift 4 and Xcode 9 and then use it in older projects, written in Swift 3 or earlier?

E.g. it would have a class that uses the new `Codable` protocol. Would that class be working in older projects?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've not tried this, but my guess is no. Since protocol is not available in swift3 you can't use it.

Comment: The rule is pretty simple. If you compile with the Swift 4 compiler (e.g. Xcode 9), then your project can contain Swift 4 and Swift 3 (there are exceptions but they're very rare in practice). If you compile with the Swift 3 compiler (e.g. Xcode 8), then you can only have Swift 3 code in your project (dependencies included).

Comment: Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, no. Xcode 9 will let you go back to Swift 3.2, but not 3.1. If you need earlier Swift compatibility, you'll have to re-download Xcode 8.3.3 which is available at https://developer.apple.com/download/

Good luck!